# Can I locate a Bank of China ATM in mainland China given the ATM ID?

Tags: online-tools, atm, china

Today I realized my ATM card is missing. (It's OK I have a spare but if that bank branch has it would still be handy.)

I used it three days ago at an ATM in Guangzhou China. I have the receipt. The receipt does not tell me the name or address of the branch. I was walking around for many hours with a friend that day not paying much attention to where we were when I needed money.

So I'm sure I can get the info from phoning the bank or going to a branch but I missed office hours. Is this something I can do online. Is there an ATM locator that includes ATM ID's for instance?

---

So far the only ATM locator I can find for the bank is [this one in Chinese](http://www.bankofchina.com/sourcedb/atmdist/406/678/679/) but doesn't include the ATM ID field.

Comment: I would presume you need to ask the bank. Maintaining a separate database would be a huge effort with little value.

Comment: @keshlam: Could be but why would the database be separate from their regular ATM database?

Comment: Ask them. Maybe it's as simple as nobody but you ever having asked. Maybe there are security reasons, though I can't think of any. Maybe that data is available to business accounts or other "premium" users.

Comment: I will but it's 2.53 AM now and they're closed, which is part of the reason I asked a question about finding an online, out-of-business-hours way. Another part is that not all bank branches in China have an English speaking staff member. Anyway that's why I came to a site for experts since the obvious non expert stuff I could think of isn't working for now.

Answer (score 2):

I did not find an **online** way to get the address of a BoC ATM from an ATM ID but I can tell you what I tried unsuccessfully and successfully to get the address:

**Going to a Bank of China branch**

At least in Guangzhou, this is painfully slow. A security guard must swipe a card in the machine that emits a slip with a number. There are a small number of tell windows. It took about 40 minutes in the nearest branch to my accommodation.

When your number is called it turns out that even an employee in a bank of BoC cannot find an ATM street address from an ATM ID. They will point out that there is a phone number on the ATM receipt:

```
客户服务热线  
            95566  
Call Center
```

**Call centre**

It turns out the call centre is available outside banking hours. I don't know if English speakers are available as I got an employee at my accommodation to call. This successfully resulted in getting the ATM address.

**On cards retained by Bank of China ATMs in China**

I didn't notice the pink details printed on the ATM receipt with my bad eyes until now but point **3.** is relevant:

> If the card is retained by the ATM because of any reason but the request from issuer bank, please claim your card with presence of the personal valid certification in the acquirer bank in 3 working days.

Basically I lost a day since I didn't get to a branch until the afternoon of the third day, which took so long, that there was no way to get to the branch that had my ATM card before closing.

Today is the fourth day. I got to the bank just after opening. My card was in the ATM. I did get it back. But it was already blocked.